# Error: EACCES, permission denied Ionic Cordova IOS

Tags: bash

I keep getting the following errors:

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/Anuraag/.cordova/lib/tmp' .
```

Whenever I try to do cordova add platform ios for my cordova app. What is the issue please help!!

Comment: Check `ls -al '/Users/Anuraag/.cordova/lib/tmp'` -- it's telling you that you do not have permission to do whatever you are trying to do to the file.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The error you have received is from NPM (since the Cordova CLI is installed via NPM). This is a tricky issue where using NPM with `sudo`, and then *not* using `sudo` will result in weird permission issues.

If you followed the instructions on the Cordova documentation, it has you install **Cordova** using `sudo`. It then has you do this:

```
# To ensure permissions are correct, run this command on Mac or Linux, changing LOGIN to match your account name:
$ sudo chown -R LOGIN /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
```

Did you do that step? If not try it. If that doesn't work, make sure the `'/Users/Anuraag/.cordova/lib/tmp'` directory can be accessed. Given that it is a local temporary directory, there is *most likely* no harm in giving it full read/write access with something like:

```
chmod -R 777 '/Users/Anuraag/.cordova/lib/tmp'
```

Comment: For mac, since I installed npm via brew, I had to do: 
`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Comment: If I run chown i get this:chown: invalid user: ‘LOGIN’.  
And when i run the chmod command I get:    chmod: cannot access ‘/Users/Anuraag/.cordova/lib/tmp’: No such file or directory. Any ideas?

Comment: @NicolasV you have to use "your" username.

Answer (score 9):

None of the solution worked for me

Finally,this work perfectly

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

Answer (score 8):

For me worked:

`sudo chown -R LOGIN  ~/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json`

Also I am using **nvm** which separates spaces and makes easier to maintain an app.

Answer (score 6):

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Comment: Please explain why you think that the owner should be changed (as opposed to, say, `chmod +X` or the like).

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME .
```

to check whats your USERNAME,
type in `whoami` in command line

Answer (score 3):

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm install -g ionic
```

Answer (score 1):

**On Mac Terminal** 
This worked for me.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to jasmo2, this worked for me:

```
sudo chown -R LOGIN ~/.config/configstore
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to uninstall cordova and ionic, then go into the user folder and deleting the hidden files .cordova and .ionic files using sudo permissions. Then reinstall cordova and ionic.

Answer (score 0):

This was what worked for me: 
`sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/YOURUSERNAME/.config`

Answer (score 0):

After trying every single solution here I had to BEGRUDGINGLY reinstall ionic

`npm i -g ionic`

Begrudgingly because my plan was to upgrade ionic to see what would break but first I wanted to run it at the current version first to see if everything still worked.