# Error While adding Cordova Platform add iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using Mac OS Sierra v10.12 and getting error while adding to my Phonegap project within the folder myApp:

```
$ node -v
v7.2.0

$ npm -v
3.10.9

$ cordova platform add ios
```

received following errors:

```
Error during untar for /Users/{user_name}/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/4.3.0/package.tgz: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/{user_name}/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/4.3.0/package/package.json'
Error: Failed to fetch platform ios
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/{user_name}/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/4.3.0/package/package.json'
```

Note: {user_name} is my mac user Id, Can anybody help me!

Comment: you have no permission to add platform

Comment: please change permission of user and project folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598377/error-eacces-permission-denied-ionic-cordova-ios

Comment: Wow, its great :) i just changed the rights and it works `$sudo chown -R {user_name} /Users/{user_name}/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/`

Comment: Thanks @SantoshShinde

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to issue with permission to add platform .

Try to following :

```
$sudo chown -R {user_name} /Users/{user_name}/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/
```

For more please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598377/error-eacces-permission-denied-ionic-cordova-ios).

Hopes this will help you !

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a cache problem of cordova. Delete the cache and try to add the platform again:

```
rm -rf ~/.cordova
```

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading npm, this worked for me:

npm install npm@latest -g